# Using word boundaries when word is adjacent to a number

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm extremely inexperienced with regex, so please bear with me. My program checks for units of measurement in the user's input and converts them from metric to imperial or vice versa. Here is a snippet of my case statement:

```
when /ltr|ltrs|liter|liters|litre|litres/
      puts "#{int} liter(s) is equal to #{calc(int, 3.78541)} gallon(s), #{rem(int, 3.78541, 4)} quart(s)!"
when /gal|gals|gallon|gallons/
      puts "#{int} gallon(s) is equal to #{calc(int, 0.264172)} liter(s), #{rem(int, 0.264172, 1000)} milliliter(s)!"
```

I would like to change the first `when` to also include `/l/`. To prevent it from being mixed up with `l`'s present in other `when` conditions (like in `gallon`), I wanted to use something like `/\bl\b/`. The issue is that this makes the program unable to recognize `l` if it is adjacent to a number, like in `20L` for example. Is there a way to make a word boundary that ignores adjacent numbers?

Comment: You have cast your question in terms of a problem you have with the way you want to solve it. Instead you need to state what you wish to achieve. Presumable, you wish to match one of several strings provided the string is not immediately preceded by X and is not immediately followed by Y. You need to tell us what X and Y are.

Comment: I was asking how to match a specific string (e.g., `l`) even when it may directly follow a number (e.g., `20l`) without another `when` condition also matching it if it happens to be part of another string (e.g., `gallon`). I'm trying to get better with regex, which is way I framed it using a regex-specific solution. Sorry I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Oh, so you want `'1.2.3gal'` to be a match but not `'10gal2'`?

Comment: I want to match a string in the first `when` condition without my second `when` condition matching that same string due to it being contained within the string which my second `when` condition is trying to match. At the same time I want it to match even though it may directly follow a number -- specifically because it's a limitation when using something like `\bstring here\b`

Comment: Although what you're suggesting would also be useful to know

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you need to formulate your question without reference to how you will solve it. Doing otherwise may limit it you to a single path when others may be available. Here you want to match the substring `'gal'` or `'gals'` or `'gallon'` or `'gallons'`, provide it satisfy certain conditions concerning what immediately precedes it in the string and what follows it in the string. Examples of possible preceding conditions are as follows: "a space, a Y, or the substring is at the beginning of the string", where "Y" might be "digit", "number" or "integer",...

Comment: ...depending on whether `'1.2.3gal'`, `2.3gal` or `'23gal'` are to be matched. Perhaps you only want to match (the string representation of) an integer, but are certain that if (say) `'gal'` is preceded by a digit the digit will be part of an integer, in which case matching a digit (or...) would be fine. What must follow the substring might be "a character that is Y or the substring is at the end of the string", where Y is "a space", "a character that is not a letter", or something else. In giving these examples I have made no mention of a regular expression...

Comment: ...Only when the requirement is made unambiguous can the regex be constructed. Moreover, in some situations an approach that does not use a regex may be best.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I will accept your criticism and try to improve my questions in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=\d|\b)L(?=\d|\b)`

You can use positive lookarounds to assert that directly beside the L is either a word boundary or a digit.

- `(?<=\d|\b)` Assert that directly before the pattern, there's a digit or a word boundary.
- `L` Match an `L`.
- `(?=\d|\b)` Assert that directly after the pattern, there's a digit or word boundary.

By using lookarounds, you can assert the existence of something without matching it. This allows you to verify the presence of digits without actually consuming them in the regex.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UIlVlh/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. I did not know about lookarounds

Answer (score 2):

Since the left word boundary can also be written as `(?<!\w)` and the right hand boundary can be written as `(?!\w)` all you need to do is to subtract a `\d` from it.

You may use it either

```
(?<![^\W\d])L(?![^\W\d])
```

or with the [*character class intersection*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html):

```
(?<![\w&&[^\d]])L(?![\w&&[^\d]])
```

And the **whole regex will look like `/(?<![^\W\d])(?:<your_regex>)(?![^\W\d])/i`**:

```
/(?<![^\W\d])l(?:trs?|it(?:er|re)s?)?(?![^\W\d])/i
/(?<![\w&&[^\d]])l(?:trs?|it(?:er|re)s?)?(?![\w&&[^\d]])/i
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://rubular.com/r/WcAIXQpIDQl5UC) and [regex demo #2](https://rubular.com/r/xSQ1JBqoXy6Tgc).

**Details**

- `(?<![^\W\d])` / `(?<![\w&&[^\d]])` - right before, there cannot be a char other than a non-word or digit chars (a leading word boundary with `\d` excluded)
- `l` - a `l` letter
- `(?:trs?|it(?:er|re)s?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `trs?` - `tr` or `trs`
  - `|` - or
  - `it(?:er|re)s?` - `it` followed with `er` or `re` and then an optional `s`
- `(?![^\W\d])` / `(?![\w&&[^\d]])` - right after, there cannot be a char other than a non-word or digit chars (a trailing word boundary with `\d` excluded)

The `i` flag will make the regex case insensitive.